# Why is the paint coming off my drywall in small bubbles?

Tags: drywall, water-damage

Not sure I've ever seen drywall pucker through paint like this; at first I was worried it was mold. Thoughts? (This is a below-ground closet wall flush with the building's exterior wall)

[image: Puckering drywall]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paint is not adhering well. I've seen that happen when a surface that was poorly primed (or not primed at all) before paint was subjected to humidity. Scrape off anything that's loose, prime (preferably with a shellac-based primer, since that sticks to both oil-based and water-based paints and vice versa), repaint.

Comment: I'd add to vacuum after scraping. My hunch is that there were air pockets left by the taper and sanding filled them with drywall dust. That should be removed even before priming.

Comment: I've seen this numerous times in the years that I worked as a painter, this is spot on. Tapers don't always do the best (or anything for that matter) to clean the dust off the walls when they're done. Painting over the dust will cause bubbles like this. Scrape, vacuum, prime, paint.